# Facebook Reach Estimate - not suficient permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to follow an example on Reach Estimate in facebook API documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reachestimate/v2.3). However I am getting an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 10
  }
}
```

My approach is to open https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, generate a token giving all permissions including `ads_management`.

And perform call:

```
act_ID/reachestimate?currency=EUR&targeting_spec={'countries':['US']}
```

Where I obtain ad account ID by going to my ads manager and reading it off URL (or by visiting power editor).

It looks simple, but I have no idea at this point what I am missing, I am also getting the same error while using PHP API.

All ideas are much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your own app to generate the access token, you are likely on the Standard or Basic tier of the Marketing API. For these tiers, you need to specify each AdAccount you are going to use.

In the developer too, select your app and go to Apps > Settings > Advanced. Under "Advertising Accounts" click the "Ads API" button on the right hand side, and list all the accounts you want to use.

For more info, see:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access#standard_accounts